# How do I connect to a PEAP encrypted wifi connection?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, internet, encryption

I need to connect to my school's wifi with Ubuntu but it is encrypted with PEAP and my current network manager doesn't support PEAP. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

PEAP should be available out of the box. There are however a lot of configurations available, though your network manager should figure this out on its own.

If you would happen to be using eduroam, here's how mine is configured:

[image: eduroam]